# What would be the correct word for “style-defining”?

Tags: from-english, росіянізм, словотворення, одним-словом

I’m having trouble finding a proper Ukrainian word for “style-defining” i.e., “the one that defines (creates) a style”. I know that this is (probably) a participle, and Ukrainian doesn’t have a lot of those, but if it is possible, I would like it to be a single word.

I’ve tried “стилеутворюючий“, but this seems to be derived from Russian. Also, there are options like “стилеутворювальний”, “стилетворчий”, but I’m not sure which one is correct, if any.

Is there such a word in Ukrainian, ignoring the “той, що утворює стиль” construct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest **стилевизначальний** as a translation. It's already being used in some scientific articles:

Лагода О.М. Худ.-образні особливості костюма в дизайні одягу кінця ХХ – початку ХХІ ст.:

> Оскільки костюм, як стилеутворююче і **стилевизначальне** явище, ідентифікатор особистості та його художньо-образні особливості в дизайні...

Соколова С. О. Префіксальний словотвір дієслів у сучасній українській мові:

> ...однак, саме архітектура стає **стилевизначальним** критерієм у процесі пошуків національної своєрідності...

Ігор Качуровський. Фоніка.:

> Усі ці щойноназвані випадки (рима строфотворча, жанротворча, **стилевизначальна** і т. п. ...

Style is "[стиль](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=style&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)", define is "[визначати](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=define%20&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)". Seems to be working.

Both "[стилеутворюючий](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8E%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk01wr0Zm6Zvex5HW08-7BgxMTJahYA:1618132879990&ei=j79yYIT3O8SMrwSLn57oCw&start=140&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjE-orc7vXvAhVExosKHYuPB704ggEQ8tMDegQIARBL&biw=1472&bih=715)" and "[стилеутворювальний](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk01IU0xzRBk7TZsVcjBRbqTrsmIxDA:1618132722822&ei=8r5yYLPTMa6OrwTGupBY&start=120&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwizlJKR7vXvAhUux4sKHUYdBAs4ggEQ8tMDegQIAhBM&biw=1472&bih=715)" are used as well. I would not oppose using any of them if I was your editor. Some editors would strongly oppose "стилеутворюючий", though.

Comment: The first quote from Lagoda suggests that "стилеутворюючий" might also be a good choice.

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky I wouldn't oppose this usage, but I know many editors who would. It's your decision at the end of the day.